# how can you filter the array of object from payperiodstartdate in angular/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter, filtering

```
[
  {
    "processId": 876,
    "processingStatus": "Completed",
    "executionTime": "00:05:59",
    "payPeriodStartDate": "2011-01-16T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "processId": 875,
    "processingStatus": "Completed",
    "payPeriodStartDate": "2019-04-14T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "processId": 874,
    "processingStatus": "Failed",
    "payPeriodStartDate": "2019-04-14T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "processId": 873,
    "processingStatus": "Completed",
    "payPeriodStartDate": "2019-04-14T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try now:

```js
data = [ { "processId": 876, "processingStatus": "Completed", "executionTime": "00:05:59", "payPeriodStartDate": "2011-01-16T00:00:00" }, { "processId": 875, "processingStatus": "Completed", "payPeriodStartDate": "2019-04-14T00:00:00" }, { "processId": 874, "processingStatus": "Failed", "payPeriodStartDate": "2019-04-14T00:00:00" }, { "processId": 873, "processingStatus": "Completed", "payPeriodStartDate": "2019-04-14T00:00:00" } ]

const filterBypay  =(srch) => data.filter(res=>res.payPeriodStartDate === srch);

console.log(filterBypay("2019-04-14T00:00:00"))

console.log(filterBypay("2011-01-16T00:00:00"))
```